# How to test with Karma Jasmine the login.service function

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I tried to test e.g. in Jasmine within Angular2 the function login but I have not idea how can I do this? This would help me to understand it better.

I tried:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { LoginComponent } from '../app/components/login/login.component';

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [LoginComponent],
        providers: [LoginService],
    });

    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    let comp = fixture.componentInstance;

    // TwainService actually injected into the component
    let loginService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(LoginService);

    // Setup spy on the `getQuote` method
    let spy = spyOn(loginService, 'login')
        .and.returnValue('true');

});
```

> **login.component.ts**

```
login() {

          this.loading = true;
          this.loginService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
              .subscribe(result => {
                  console.log(result);
                  if (result == true) {

                      this.router.navigate(['/start']);

                  } else {
                    this.error = 'Wrong password';
                    this.errorStatus = true;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      this.errorStatus = false;
                    }, 1500);

                      this.loading = false;
                  }
              });
      }
```

Comment: Clarify: what do you want to test? The login() method of your component, or the login() method of your service?

Comment: Hello JB Nizet, I want to test both. I am trying to understand how it works with my coded example. Thanx

Comment: Then you need two tests: one for your service, and one for your component. When testing your component, you should mock, or spy on your service. The documentation has explanations and examples of component tests that use a service dependency. Read it and try something: https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component-with-a-dependency

Comment: I already saw this documentation..

Comment: Read it again, then, and do what its explanations and examples do. If you can't understand these explanations, why would you understand mine?

Comment: Because I wrote this service. It is different..

Comment: What your service does is completely irrelevant to the test of the component. You must mock the service to test the component.

Comment: Ok, I did it but I am getting error like Error: No provider for LoginService. I changed my test spec see above

Comment: Why in hell do you create a testing module with a LoginComponent in order to test your LoginService? If you want to test te LoginService, and you want angular to create and inject the LoginService, then the testing module doesn't need any component. But it needs a provider for the LoginService.

Comment: Why? In this example it is also using the component welcome for example

Comment: But it doesn't test the service. It tests the component, by mocking its dependency. The title of the section is "Test a component with a dependency". Not "Test a service".

Comment: How can I for example pass credentials to test the login service?